# New to Python and not understanding the result of the code below

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

In python this code returns the number 7.  Can someone please provide an explanation to why this is the case?

```
mystring = "I love Python"
x = mystring.find("Python")
print(x)
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: `find("Python")` returns the start position of the string. Python indexes from zero, so if you count charaters in `mystring` you'll count 0,1,2,3,4,5,6, and then 7 is the position of P in Python.

Comment: When you're looking for an explanation, you should always [start with the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find).

Comment: @mako212 Thank you for the quick response and this really helps.  I learned about the counting using lists, but not strings so I was a little confused.

Comment: @Mark Ransom - I agree Mark I should have gone there for the find function.  I was reviewing an online guide that has code related to string variables and could not find the explanation in the guide and came across this site.  Thanks again for not making a newby in coding feel dumb.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be the case? I mean, what were you expecting instead? maybe 8 or 6?  Or an error? BTW, welcome to SO! Check out [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 4):

The `find()` method finds the first occurrence of the specified value. In your code, you are searching for the word `Python`. The first occurrence of `Python` comes at index 7 (index starts from 0).

```py
string.find(value, start, end)
```

These are other arguments which `find()` takes.

*value* = What word you want to search

*start* = the start index

*end* = The last index